# Run PHP-CLI Without Quiet Mode

Tags: php

It seems that by default, PHP-CLI now runs solely in quiet mode, instead of requiring the user to pass `-q` or `--no-header`.

For example, if `phptest.php` is the following:

```
<?php header("Location: http://www.something.com"); ?>
```

We can request it using cURL and an Apache server, with the following result:

```
$ curl -I "http://localhost/phptest.php"

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 20 Mar 2018 16:47:48 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.24
Location: http://www.something.com
Content-Type: text/html
```

But if we request through the PHP-CLI, we get nothing:

```
$ php /var/www/phptest.php
```

My question, then, is how can I get the PHP-CLI to return headers as well? If it's not possible, what alternatives exist (short of cURLing or `wget`ing it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `php-cgi` instead of `php`:

```
$ php-cgi /var/www/phptest.php

Status: 302 Moved Temporarily
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.32
Location: http://www.something.com
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```